# Remove a particular pixel value from image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to create Deep Learning Classifier For which I have Image data.
Consider the following image:

[image]

I want remove all the black background from image which corresponds to pixel Value 0 
as it creates lot of noise for network to learn.

I tried the following Approach which takes in image 
I converted it into numpy array
+Flatten the Array
+removed all the pixel value corresponding to 0
and tried to resize it into Original Shape but it didn't work as expected
[image]

Comment: If you remove that pixel how will you recreate the same image again? The dimensions will be lost. You have replace those pixels with some other value

Comment: Moreover if all your images have the same background it shouldn't be a problem for the learning algorithm

Comment: An image is a rectangular raster, or a grid, with intensity values in each pigeon hole. You can't *"remove"* values because the empty hole in the grid will remain, so, given that there must be something in each hole, you might as well have black, or zero, which is least distracting for your neural networks.

Comment: You could simply replace these pixels with `NaN`, if your learning algorithm can handle that:
`image[image == 0] = np.nan`
This only works if your image is of `dtype` float. If it's integer based, convert first.